# Show that if $\gamma$ is any isometry on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then so is $a\gamma(\dfrac{1}{a})$

Tags: group-theory

Take $v \in \mathbb{R}$
and denote translation over $v$ as $\tau v$. Let a ∈ $\mathbb{R}$ with $a \neq 0$.

a) Verify that $a \tau_v \dfrac{1}{a} $ is again a translation

b) Show that if $\gamma$ is any isometry on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then so is $a\gamma(\dfrac{1}{a})$

I'm stuck at both of these questions, can somebody help?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: (a) $\tau_v(x)=x+v$. Therefore, $a\tau_v(x/a)=x+av=\tau_{av}(x)$.

Comment: (b) If $\gamma$ is an isometry, then $d(a\gamma(x/a),a\gamma(y/a))=|a|d(\gamma(x/a),\gamma(y/a))=|a|d(x/a,y/a)=d(x,y)$.

Comment: Ah ok! Next time I'll post my progress. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

These both answer easily by applying the definitions of things.

$\tau_v:x\mapsto x+v$ is a translation, and $\rho_a:x\mapsto ax$ would be a dilation.

So $a\tau_v\frac1a$ can be thought of as three things:

- 1) $x\mapsto x/a$,
- 2) $x/a\mapsto x/a+v$
- 3) $x/a+v\mapsto a(x/a)+av=x+av$

---

Next, what is an isometry? Here it's a transformation that preserves the Euclidean metric, rather than some other metric. What properties does this metric satisfy?